# How to invoke another BPEL as a subprocess

Tags: wsdl, informatica, bpel

I am trying to create a workflow solution in ActiveVOS that connects to Informatica P360. I am trying to create 2 BPELs, one for the actual workflow and another one that performs a specific task. How do I invoke another BPEL from main process?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the community! Can you help us a little bit to help you? Post details of your setup, show us what works, what does not, show the error. This will help a lot! Go ahead and check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you get the solution?